# How to write data to file from web table. The values changes quickly

Tags: python, parsing, streaming

There are lots libraries in Python websockets, asincio and ect. I need to write continuous changing data from web table to file. The data is generated probably by ajax. Can get data by simple request, but I don't want to DOS http server. Should be some solution to establish connection and just read changing data.

The data is in span_class="up"

+4.24%

Comment: Find out how the webpage gets the data. Is it a repeated ajax request to a specific endpoint? A websocket? Once you know, you can emulate the method and the timing, and be sure that's you aren't hurting the server.

Comment: ttps://push.ttweb.net/http_push/